# Serve a html/jss/css application from CDN or application server (RoR, node.js etc)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, cdn

I'm doing a rich internet application (html/js/css) which has to communicate with a backend application server (RoR or node.js) through XHR/Websocket.

I wonder what the best way is to serve the RIA files to the web browsers: CDN or RoR/node.js as static file servers?

Does't the latter make it impossible for the browser to communicate with the backend server due to the same origin policy?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same origin policy applies to requests, not static files.

You are on www.test.com

```
$.get('api.someotherorigin.com/things.json', function(res){
    // I'll get a same origin policy error
});
```

This is why people use getJSON/jsonp in these cases. It even applies to subdomains, depending on how things are set up.

A cdn has the benefits of serving your static files from a cookieless, often geolocation optimized source. You almost certainly don't need this during development.

The benefits later on are that you are likely going to have only a few servers (or just one) located in a spot that may favor people in one location and give a crappy RTT for folks not close. Additionally, your domain is going to likely have cookies for authentication, sessionid, etc etc -- if you use a cdn, you avoid sending these cookies along with every single subsequent request for static files, reducing the over all request/response sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Just host the files yourself. You can serve static files quite easily using `connect`

[`connect.static`](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-static.html)

You may request *popular* JavaScript files from a cdn if you want to take advantage of caching. [jscdn](http://www.cdnjs.com/) and [google cdn](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) are popular.

But your own personal HTML/CSS files should be on a static file server. (You can use something else like nginx to serve those through a sub domain if you want )

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, that means CSS and static HTML should come from Apache(or whatever) and the dynamic stuff from node?

Comment: @drachenstern ryan dahl himself says that node.js does not perform highly as a static file server. he recommends you use nginx instead)